# Outlook VBA Convert .xls attachment to .xlsx

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have the following code snippet from some Outlook VBA code I am creating to automatically export and file a bunch of excel attachments we are getting each day:

```
Atmt.SaveAsFile FullFileName_And_Path
```

Atmt stands for attachment and represents the current attachment that VBA is looping through.
FullFileName_And_Path and is a string which contains the filename and path that it needs to save it as.

The problem I am having is that some of these attachments are in the old .xls format.  Now, when a human does this, they open the file and simply save it as a .xlsx file...  Is there command I can use to make VBA simply convert the file to xlsx?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook cannot do this directly. You need to save a temporary copy of the file, then create an instance of Excel, open the file with Excel, save it as the new format, then close Excel.

So first, add a reference to Excel in the VBA editor goto Tools->References and add `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library` (Note, 14 is Excel 2010, the number may be different depending on your Office version)

Then something like this should work (untested code):

```
Public Sub ConvertXlsToXlsx(Atmt As Attachment, FullFileName_And_Path As String)
  Dim tempPath As String
  Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

  tempPath = Environ("TEMP") & "\converttemp.xls"
  Atmt.SaveAsFile tempPath

  ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(tempPath)
  wb.SaveAs FullFileName_And_Path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  wb.Close False
  Set wb = Nothing
  ExcelApp.Quit
  Set ExcelApp = Nothing

  Kill wb 'Clean up the temp file
End Sub
```

Comment: AndASM,

Thanks, I was thinking this is what I would have to do, but wanted to make sure there wasn't some other method I didn't know about.  Tomorrow I will work on implementing this and then report back on how it goes! :)